# GDAL version in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

When calling `GdalUtils.version()`, the returned information is

> "2010100"

While I can identify GDAL2, I´m unsure about the next version steps. It could be `2.1.1` or `2.0.1` or `2.1.1`.

Currently, the newest GDAL is `2.1.2` so I assume that it means `2.1.1`. Can somebody verify that?

Also, the output of `GdalUtils.version()` should be updated to return proper version information.

Here is the complete Python script (macOS):

```
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import ogr
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents', True)
app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
sys.path.append(r'/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

from processing.algs.gdal.GdalUtils import GdalUtils
GdalUtils.version()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that the version comes directly from GDAL. See the source code https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/gcore/gdal_version.h. Probably GDAL and QGIS developers would appreciate if you could show a place where to improve the documentation.

The code looks like this:

```
/* GDAL_COMPUTE_VERSION macro introduced in GDAL 1.10 */
/* Must be used ONLY to compare with version numbers for GDAL >= 1.10 */
#ifndef GDAL_COMPUTE_VERSION
#define GDAL_COMPUTE_VERSION(maj,min,rev) ((maj)*1000000+(min)*10000+(rev)*100)
#endif
```

With this formula your version is 2.1.1.

Comment: Thanks! Well, my suggesting would be to place proper points between `maj`  , `min` and `rev` so that `GdalUtils.version()` returns `2.1.1` instead of `2010100`. I´ll open a ticket.

Comment: Isn't that code for computers and not for humans? For computers it is easy to find that 2010100<2010200 but not as easy to compare strings 2.1.1 and 2.1.2, or 2.1.11.

Comment: Maybe the output is needed in this format in other functions. Then I´ll just do a local modification. I´ll see what the QGIS team thinks.

Answer (score 2):

According to your path ( */Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins*) you work on Mac OS X. If you use a version of [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/), GDAL is installed in */Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework* and you don't need QGIS to return the proper GDAL version information.

If you have followed the procedure outlined in the ReadMe.rtf file ([GDAL_Framework-2.1.2-1.dmg](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Framework-2.1.2-1.dmg))

You can type in the Terminal.app

```
gdalinfo --version
```

Or in the Python shell

```
from osgeo import gdal
print gdal.__version__
```

Because you can perfectly use the GDAL library without QGIS

Comment: My system-wide GDAL is installed using `homebrew`. Regardless, I try to access QGIS GDAL platform independent using the `processing` module from QGIS. So I need to use the `GdalUtils` way.